# Serializing an integer as hexadecimal in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, hex

JSON.NET supports [deserializing hexadecimal numbers](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/04/16/json-net-3-5-release-7-bson-binary-json-part-deux) (e.g. `0xffff`), but how about **serializing**?

The following works, but seems far too complicated:

```
public sealed class HexJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(uint).Equals(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue($"0x{value:x}");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanRead => false;
}
```

I am looking for something along the lines of [DateFormatHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateFormatHandling.htm), only for integers.

Comment: The `JsonTextReader` for Newtonsoft.Json handles many more behind-the-scenes conversions compared to the `JsonTextWriter`. The JSON format doesn't support hexadecimal, so I would put the value inside a string. What you have works otherwise.

Comment: That's the easiest way I know.  Other option would be to subclass `JsonTextWriter` and override methods like [`JsonTextWriter.WriteValue(Int32)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_WriteValue_10.htm).  Hex format numbers explicitly violate the [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) (unlike dates for which there is [no official JSON representation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/datesinjson.htm)) which may be why hex format output is not built-in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, hexadecimal literals are not allowed in JSON (contrary to JavaScript).

## Converter

Converts `uint` values to hexadecimal *string literals* and vice versa:

```
public sealed class HexStringJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(uint).Equals(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue($"0x{value:x}");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var str = reader.ReadAsString();
        if (str == null || !str.StartsWith("0x"))
            throw new JsonSerializationException();
        return Convert.ToUInt32(str);
    }
}
```

## Usage example

```
public sealed class CanonInfo
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(HexStringJsonConverter))]
    public uint ModelId { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(HexStringJsonConverter))]
    public uint FirmwareRevision { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This code has a bug in it. It should be Convert.ToUInt32(str, 16).

Comment: @markf78 This code has been successfully tested in production for quite a few years, check out https://github.com/CHDKUtil/CHIMP

Comment: The ReadJson method will throw a FormatException if str = "0x20". Please see https://onlinegdb.com/Sk8dkCzqw for a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

The below code should work for serialization in your `HexJsonConverter` class

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
     if(reader.ValueType.FullName == typeof(string).FullName)
    {
        string str = (string)reader.Value;
        if (str == null || !str.StartsWith("0x"))
            throw new JsonSerializationException();
        return Convert.ToUInt32(str.Substring("0x".Length), 16);
    }
    else
        throw new JsonSerializationException();
}
```