# Deserialize hexadecimal values with Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, json.net, hex, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize json into a C# object. The json basically looks like this:

```
{ "hexValue": "0x9a7f" }
```

My POCO looks like this:

```
public class HexTest
{
     public int hexValue;
}
```

I've read in a link from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481456/serializing-an-integer-as-hexadecimal-in-json-net) that Newtonsoft supports deserializing hex values. But in all fairness, those release notes were published a decade ago. I've even read in some source code on [github 
published here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs) what appears to be code to deserialize a hex formatted string that starts with "0x". Yet, when I try to deserialize a hex value, I always get the following exception:

> Could not convert string to int: 0x9a7f.

It doesn't matter what type I try. I've tried using int long decimal Decimal, etc... From reading the source it looked like the Decimal type should have worked but nothing works. Does Newtonsoft really have support for converting hex values defined as strings into a numeric data type of some kind?

Sure, I know I can use the information in the question I linked to above to implement custom support for it but I'd really rather use the built-in support if it's there.

Comment: Did you try `{ "hexValue": 0x9a7f }` ? Or do you really actually mean that to be string?

Comment: lol, holy $#@! I did try that at first but it was when I was trying to use an int type in my POCO. it choked with a different exception. However, now that I tried it without quotes AND with the decimal type, it works!!!!! Thank you!! Can't believe I didn't think about trying that before posting the question. I wish that was better documented. A search for hexadecimal on the newtonsoft documentation site produces 0 results. In fact, I must have done something else to screw it up before because it seems to be correctly parsing all the numeric data types just fine now. Weird.

Comment: Maybe, now that you know what works, you can write an elaborate answer to your own question, so other people with the same problem can profit and save themselves an unguided tour through documentation hell? My suggestion was merely a shot into the blue ... so _you_ should actually be more able to tell _why_ this works.

Comment: I was expecting to give you credit for answering it, but sure, I'd be happy to.

Comment: As I said, it was merely a shot into the blue. I couldn't (really) explain _why_ this works and where it is documented ... so, not much to be credited for. You did the work.

Comment: I did intend for that to be a string. Originally it wasn't but when I hit my first exception, I though I might have an invalid JSON format...and, in fact I did. So I thought that might be what was causing the exception and converted it to a string. That just resulted in a different exception and that's when I started into the research and ultimately the resulted in this question.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comments to my original question above by Fildor, I was able to resolve the problem by removing quotes around the value in the JSON so it now read like this:

```
{ "hexValue": 0x9a7f }
```

Also, further testing reveals that any of the numeric data types work for this in the POCO including int, long, and decimal. It is probably worth noting that (not sure about the latest standard) most if not all JSON validators will consider this invalid JSON because hexadecimal is not a valid JSON numeric data type.

Taking another look at the source, it's clear why this works and not the string. The parser will only call the method that detects the 0x prefix if it recognizes the json value token as a numeric type which, if quoted, it cannot do because by definition, that is a string.