# HttpClient REST API PUT request returns code 500

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I use REST API of some web server to control data exchange between various devices. I implement my ideas in C# application using HttpClient class, GET, DELETE, POST requests work perfectly.
However some API function requires PUT request with a JSON/string data provided as a content and in that case I get Error 500 (internal server error).

```cs
    public class RegBank
    {
        public int Address { get; set; }
        public int NumRegisters { get; set; }
    }    
    
    // static HttpClient obj instantiated at the beginning of the app 
    public static httpClient = new HttpClient();
    
    ...
    
    // create an object and serialize into JSON string
    var obj = new RegBank {Address = 0x40, NumRegisters = 123};
    string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); // using Newtonsoft.Json library
    
    // compose HttpRequestMessage
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, url);
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Auth-Token", "token");
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Auth-User", "user");
    request.Content = new StringContent(jsonStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    
    response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request); // yields Error 500
```

If I comment out `request.Content = new StringContent(jsonStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");` line the server responds with Error 400 which indicates server is alive and authentication passes but the data is missing.
Interestingly, when doing POST requests under similar conditions (auth, content) they succeed perfectly.

Just to confirm the server itself processes such requests I also tried performing the same operation using Python and it works perfectly

```py
response = requests.put(
    url,
    headers={'X-Auth-Token': "token", 'X-Auth-User': "user", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    json= { "Address" : 0x40, "NumRegisters" : 123 }
)
```

What do I miss in configuring HttpClient or HttpRequestMessage?
Thanks.

Comment: `NumRegisters` is an `int` so the Json representation will be `64` and not `0x40`

Comment: If that is the problem then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43481456/serializing-an-integer-as-hexadecimal-in-json-net) may be a starting point

Comment: Oops sorry it’s `Address` which is represented as `0x40` in the working code

Answer (score 0):

The server seems to process it, however its an internal Server Error, that seems to be some issue with processing the data,
Could you try adding 0x40 in quotes in the json like a string.
Also try the json with just one parameter update using the PUT request, which is the numberRegister to see if its a datatype issue.

Comment: The working (Python) code doesn’t have `0x40` as a string value though

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer to my question.
The real reasoning, like it was proposed others was still the wrongly prepared StringContent object.

I used [HttpToolkit](https://httptoolkit.com/) to compare the request data sent by Python code with that of C# code and find out the difference.